# How to delete a document from Elasticsearch cluster by searching exact using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

You can insert the data with below commands, example i have put 3 documents, but I have something around more than 1000 documents

```
test = [{'id':1,'name': 'A', 'subject': ['Maths', 'Accounting'],
        'type':'Contract', 'Location':'NY'},
    { 'id':2,  'name': 'AB', 'subject': ['Physics', 'Engineering'],
    'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'},
    {'id':3,   'name': 'ABC',   'subject': ['Maths', 'Engineering'],
    'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'}]

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
for e in test:
        es.index(index="myindex", body=e, id=e['id'])
```

- I need to delete documents from if `name` matches `AB`

I tried with below commands

```
names = ['AB']
for name in names:
   es.delete_by_query(index="myindex", body={'name': name})
```

- I got parsing exception, Unknown key for VALUE_STRING in [name]
- While inserting into index i can ignore the name with `AB`, but here I need to delete from the index if name matches `AB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an actual query to the `body` Argument of the `delete_by_query` function. something like this:

```
for name in names:
   es.delete_by_query(index="myindex", body={
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": name
        }
    }
})

# or if you cant update the doc mapping for the field: name

for name in names:
   es.delete_by_query(index="myindex", body={
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "name.keyword": name
        }
    }
})
```

Remeber that the `term`-query used here only gives you exact matches.
Here is some further reading: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.10.0/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.delete_by_query of the Api-Documentation

#### Update on the used query:

- `term` is used to query exact values, the docs. also state the term should not be used on text-fields
- on text-fields you should use a `match` query, which returns docs whitin a certain score
- to get a exact match in this case you could do a `term`-query on the id or update your doc-mapping, so that the name-field is a keyword
- you could also update the query with `.keyword`, but this is not advised as general solution because it has a negative impact on query-perfromance (the word tokenization is done in query-time not on index-time)

Furhter reading:

- term: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current//query-dsl-term-query.html
- match: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current//query-dsl-match-query.html
- text vs. keyword: https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

Comment: just quick question even i have a lot of documents will it search entire documents in index

Comment: it searchs all docs in the specified index, and only deletes those which exactly match the query

Comment: body={
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "name.keyword": name
        }
    }
}

Comment: If you need the addtional .keyword a term query is probably not the right fit for your search-query, have a look at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current//query-dsl-term-query.html  also the way a Keyword is tokenized is different to a normal text-field have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html. You could also update your mapping and set the name field to type: keyword. As i wrote, A term query is used to return docs which precisely match the query.

Comment: But Erik, I tried to search without keyword, I got zero document, I got output only with 'name.keyword'

Comment: I have searched with  I got correct output with { "query": { "term": { "id": 2 } } },, but { "query": { "term": { "name": 'AB' } } I didn't correct output,    If i change { "query": { "term": { "name.keyword": 'AB' } } then i got correct output

Comment: As the documentation states: `To search text field values, use the match query instead` so one thing you can do is change the query to: ```{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "A"
        }
    }
}```   
Or change the mapping of the Field `name` to keyword, but i would recommend using match.  If you want to know which Fieldtypes your indices have you can do: `curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex'`. I also updated the answer.

Comment: will match query matches the exact match, because I need exact match

Comment: also, it any problem if i use name.keyword

Comment: No it will match within a certain score, if you need the exact match you could either: query based on the `id` or make `name` a keyword.  Here is some further explanation https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

Comment: it is in your case probably no problem, but it degrades the performance, especially if you have alot docs and the field which is tokenzied ist a very long string

Comment: Can you update the answer with exact match also?

Comment: updated the answer with the comment findings